# jQuery custom content scroller - horizontal and vertical scroller

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

on start i write my english i liitle.

I have problem. How in 'jquery-custom-content-scroller' (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) do scroll bars to be horizontally and vertically. I would like to show scroolbars when it is needed.

Comment: Do you want in the same content tag ( div for example ) having two scrollbars? one vertical and another one horizontal?

Comment: Yes, I have problem add horizontal and vertical scrollbar to this same tag (<div>). Script add only vertical or horizontal scrollbar to one tag.